# Flutter Firebase connection: The method was called on null, Receiver: null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, methods, google-cloud-firestore

I try to connect my App to Firestore, to store the data there. I worked very, very long on this problem but I cannot find the solution, it would be really great if someone could show me my mistake.

There is always the Error:
"NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getTodos' was called on null. Receiver: null, Tried calling: getTodos()"
if I try to run the App.

This is my main Page:

```css
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'database.dart';





class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  FirebaseUser user;
  DatabaseService database;





  void addItem(String key) {
    database.setTodo(key, false);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void deleteItem(String key) {
    database.deleteTodo(key);
  }

  void toggleDone(String key, bool value) {
    database.setTodo(key, !value);
  }










  Future<void> connectToFirebase() async {
    final FirebaseAuth authenticate = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential result = await authenticate.signInAnonymously();
    user = result.user;
    database = DatabaseService(user.uid);


    if (!(await database.checkIfUserExists())) {
      database.setTodo('Todo anlegen', false);
    }
  }




  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectToFirebase();
  }






  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Test'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 152, 185, 100),
          ),

          body: FutureBuilder(
          // Wait until [connectToFirebase] returns stream
          future: connectToFirebase(),

              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            else {
              // When stream exists, use StreamBuilder to wait for data
            return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(

                stream: database.getTodos(),

                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  else {
                    // resolve stream... Stream<DocumentSnapshot> -> DocumentSnapshot -> Map<String, bool>
                    Map<String, dynamic> items = snapshot.data.data as Map<String, dynamic>;

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      String key = items.keys.elementAt(i);
                      return ToDoItemAufgaben(
                        key,
                        items[key],
                            () => deleteItem(key),
                            () => toggleDone(key, items[key]),
    );
    },
    );
    }
    });
    }}));
  }}
```

This is my Database Page:

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {

  final String userID;

  DatabaseService(this.userID);

  final CollectionReference userTodos = Firestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

  Future setTodo(String key, bool value) async {
    return await userTodos.document(userID).setData(
        {key: value});
  }

  Future deleteTodo(String key) async {
    return await userTodos.document(userID).updateData({
      key: FieldValue.delete(),
    });
  }

  Future checkIfUserExists() async {
    if ((await userTodos.document(userID).get()).exists) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Stream getTodos() {
      return userTodos.document(userID).snapshots();
  }


}
```

Thank you very much if you take your time and look at my problem, it would be great if you could help me!

Thanks, Nico

Comment: Have you checked if your google-services.json / GoogleService-Info.plist is correctly configured? You might also want to make sure the application ID you used in Firestore is correct.

Comment: Hi, these should be correct, for example, the authentification with firebase in my App works, "userTodos" is the correct ID. May you have another idea?